# Unusual hits in Apache log for localhost site

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, traffic, attacks

I have an Apache 2.2 webserver running on Windows 7 with six virtual hosts set up.

- Domain name A points to `?:/.../urls/1/`
- Domain name B points to `?:/.../urls/2/`
- Domain name C+D point to `?:/.../urls/3/`
- Domain name E* points to `?:/.../urls/4/`
- My public IP points to `?:/.../urls/5/`
- Localhost + network IP point to `?:/.../urls/6/`

(pseudo-addresses and paths)

**Edit: Actual order in config**

- **Localhost + network IP point to** `?:/.../urls/6/`
- **My public IP points to** `?:/.../urls/5/`
- **Domain name A points to** `?:/.../urls/1/`
- **Domain name B points to** `?:/.../urls/2/`
- **Domain name C+D point to** `?:/.../urls/3/`
- **Domain name E* points to** `?:/.../urls/4/`

**End Edit**

I don't own domain name E yet, so for now I have it defined in my hosts file, and it works when I try to access it in a browser by the domain name.

I've been doing some extensive file structure changes and altered my virtual hosts a bit, so for now each site is just showing a test page that simply states which site it is.  Domain name A/B/C/etc.  Each site has its own access log and error log.  All seemingly straightforward stuff.  Having a private site on localhost is new to me.  In the past, localhost, network IP and domain name A all pointed to my main site so there was no consideration for privacy.

What concerns me now is that site 6, which should only be accessible by `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `192.168.1.100`, is recording hits from external addresses in the access log.  This site denies from all except my own addresses, and the foreign requests have resulted in 403 as expected, whether they attempt to access real files like index.html or something bogus, though a few requests have resulted in a 400 error which I'm not familiar with.  When certain common errors are triggered, I redirect to a custom error script with `?code=$HTTP_CODE` to dump %ENV data to a file in the hopes that I can glean some useful information about these hits and also return an error page to the user.  Nothing as of yet makes any sense to me.

I want to know how/why these requests are reaching my internal addresses, if I should be worried about anything in `?:/.../urls/6/` being visible to the public, if I have misconfigured anything in Apache, and if so, how to fix it.

Here are some snippets that might be relevant.  Paths and my web addresses have been obfuscated.

hosts file

```
127.0.0.1        domain-name-E.com          # domain that i don't own yet
127.0.0.1        www.domain-name-E.com      # domain that i don't own yet
```

httpd-vhosts.conf **Edit: Adjusted to show actual order of VHs**

```
<Directory "?:/.../urls/">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:80

# site 6: private
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "?:/.../urls/6/www/"

    ServerName  localhost
    ServerAlias 127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias 192.168.1.100

    ScriptAlias /cgi/ "?:/.../urls/6/cgi/"
    <Directory "?:/.../urls/6/cgi/">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog  "?:/.../logs/errors-site6.log"

  # CustomLog "?:/.../logs/access-site6.log" common
    LogFormat "%{%Y/%m/%d (%a) at %H:%M:%S}t    %a  Login: %u   Sent: %B B in %D µs   Status: %s/%>s for %H %m %{Host}i%U%q Using: %{User-agent}i   From: %{Referer}i" custom
    CustomLog "?:/.../logs/access-site6.log" custom env=!dontlog

    SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1"       dontlog
    SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "192\.168\.1\..*"    dontlog
    SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "XXX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX" dontlog # my public IP address
</VirtualHost>

# site 5 here
# site 1 here
# site 2 here
# site 3 here
# site 4 here
```

?:/.../urls/6/.htaccess

```
# site 6: private

Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 192.168.1
Allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX # my public IP address
```

?:/.../logs/access-site6.log (alignment tidied up a bit)

```
# timestamp                    # IP                                                                                   #  domain/path?query                # agent                                                             # referrer
2019/06/24 (Mon) at 18:50:52   61.219.11.153    Login: -   Sent:  226 B in   3001 µs   Status: 400/400 for HTTP/1.1 GET       -/                          Using: -                                                            From: -
2019/06/24 (Mon) at 19:08:14   104.152.52.22    Login: -   Sent: 1211 B in 512029 µs   Status: 403/403 for HTTP/1.0 GET       -/?code=403                 Using: masscan/1.0 (https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan)   From: -
2019/06/25 (Tue) at 00:12:51   138.99.29.110    Login: -   Sent:  226 B in   3001 µs   Status: 400/400 for HTTP/1.1 GET       -/Login.htm                 Using: -                                                            From: -
2019/06/25 (Tue) at 02:26:21   122.116.24.230   Login: -   Sent:  226 B in   3000 µs   Status: 400/400 for HTTP/1.1 GET       -/Login.htm                 Using: -                                                            From: -
2019/06/25 (Tue) at 04:21:55   92.63.194.15     Login: -   Sent: 1211 B in 365021 µs   Status: 403/403 for HTTP/0.9 GET       -/?code=403                 Using: -                                                            From: -
2019/06/25 (Tue) at 09:28:05   89.248.169.12    Login: -   Sent: 1211 B in 309018 µs   Status: 403/403 for HTTP/1.1 GET      80/?code=403                 Using: Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x                                        From: -
2019/06/25 (Tue) at 10:07:53   185.53.88.37     Login: -   Sent:    0 B in 384022 µs   Status: 403/403 for HTTP/1.0 GET       -/robots.txt?code=403       Using: -                                                            From: -
2019/06/25 (Tue) at 10:48:16   77.247.110.106   Login: -   Sent:    0 B in 464027 µs   Status: 403/403 for HTTP/1.0 GET       -/robots.txt?code=403       Using: -                                                            From: -
2019/06/25 (Tue) at 13:46:30   192.31.231.241   Login: -   Sent: 1211 B in 519029 µs   Status: 403/403 for HTTP/1.1 GET default/.html?code=403            Using: curl/7.64.1                                                  From: -
2019/06/25 (Tue) at 15:14:24   77.247.110.106   Login: -   Sent:    0 B in 375022 µs   Status: 403/403 for HTTP/1.0 GET       -/robots.txt?code=403       Using: -                                                            From: -
2019/06/25 (Tue) at 21:00:55   220.133.33.166   Login: -   Sent:  226 B in   3001 µs   Status: 400/400 for HTTP/1.1 GET       -/Login.htm                 Using: -                                                            From: -
2019/06/26 (Wed) at 01:33:22   110.249.212.46   Login: -   Sent:  226 B in   2000 µs   Status: 400/400 for HTTP/1.1 GET       -/testget?q=23333&port=80   Using: -                                                            From: -
```

?:/.../logs/errors-site6.log

```
[Mon Jun 24 18:50:52 2019] [error] [client 61.219.11.153]  client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /
[Mon Jun 24 19:08:14 2019] [error] [client 104.152.52.22]  client denied by server configuration: ?:/.../urls/6/www/
[Tue Jun 25 00:12:51 2019] [error] [client 138.99.29.110]  client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /Login.htm
[Tue Jun 25 02:26:21 2019] [error] [client 122.116.24.230] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /Login.htm
[Tue Jun 25 04:21:55 2019] [error] [client 92.63.194.15]   client denied by server configuration: ?:/.../urls/6/www/
[Tue Jun 25 09:28:05 2019] [error] [client 89.248.169.12]  client denied by server configuration: ?:/.../urls/6/www/
[Tue Jun 25 10:07:53 2019] [error] [client 185.53.88.37]   client denied by server configuration: ?:/.../urls/6/www/robots.txt
[Tue Jun 25 10:48:17 2019] [error] [client 77.247.110.106] client denied by server configuration: ?:/.../urls/6/www/robots.txt
[Tue Jun 25 13:46:30 2019] [error] [client 192.31.231.241] client denied by server configuration: ?:/.../urls/6/www/.html
[Tue Jun 25 15:14:24 2019] [error] [client 77.247.110.106] client denied by server configuration: ?:/.../urls/6/www/robots.txt
[Tue Jun 25 21:00:55 2019] [error] [client 220.133.33.166] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /Login.htm
[Wed Jun 26 01:33:22 2019] [error] [client 110.249.212.46] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /testget
```

?:/.../logs/detail-site6.log (alignment tidied up a bit and some irrelevant key/val pairs omitted)

```
2019/06/24 at 07:08:15 PM
$VAR1 = {
  'DOCUMENT_ROOT'           => '?:/.../urls/6/www/',
  'GATEWAY_INTERFACE'       => 'CGI/1.1',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT'             => '*/*',
  'HTTP_USER_AGENT'         => 'masscan/1.0 (https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan)',
  'QUERY_STRING'            => 'code=403',
  'REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
  'REDIRECT_STATUS'         => '403',
  'REDIRECT_URL'            => '/',
  'REMOTE_ADDR'             => '104.152.52.22',
  'REMOTE_PORT'             => '48100',
  'REQUEST_METHOD'          => 'GET',
  'REQUEST_URI'             => '/',
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME'         => '?:/.../urls/6/cgi/error/.pl',
  'SCRIPT_NAME'             => '/cgi/error/.pl',
  'SERVER_ADDR'             => '192.168.1.100',
  'SERVER_NAME'             => 'localhost',
  'SERVER_PORT'             => '80',
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL'         => 'HTTP/1.0',
  'SERVER_SIGNATURE'        => '',
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE'         => 'Apache',
};

2019/06/25 at 04:21:55 AM
$VAR1 = {
  'DOCUMENT_ROOT'           => '?:/.../urls/6/www/',
  'GATEWAY_INTERFACE'       => 'CGI/1.1',
  'QUERY_STRING'            => 'code=403',
  'REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD' => '',
  'REDIRECT_STATUS'         => '403',
  'REDIRECT_URL'            => '/',
  'REMOTE_ADDR'             => '92.63.194.15',
  'REMOTE_PORT'             => '1468',
  'REQUEST_METHOD'          => 'GET',
  'REQUEST_URI'             => '',
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME'         => '?:/.../urls/6/cgi/error/.pl',
  'SCRIPT_NAME'             => '/cgi/error/.pl',
  'SERVER_ADDR'             => '192.168.1.100',
  'SERVER_NAME'             => 'localhost',
  'SERVER_PORT'             => '80',
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL'         => 'HTTP/0.9',
  'SERVER_SIGNATURE'        => '',
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE'         => 'Apache',
};

2019/06/25 at 09:28:05 AM
$VAR1 = {
  'DOCUMENT_ROOT'           => '?:/.../urls/6/www/',
  'GATEWAY_INTERFACE'       => 'CGI/1.1',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT'             => '*/*',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'    => 'gzip',
  'HTTP_HOST'               => '80',
  'HTTP_USER_AGENT'         => 'Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x',
  'QUERY_STRING'            => 'code=403',
  'REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
  'REDIRECT_STATUS'         => '403',
  'REDIRECT_URL'            => '/',
  'REMOTE_ADDR'             => '89.248.169.12',
  'REMOTE_PORT'             => '32902',
  'REQUEST_METHOD'          => 'GET',
  'REQUEST_URI'             => '/',
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME'         => '?:/.../urls/6/cgi/error/.pl',
  'SCRIPT_NAME'             => '/cgi/error/.pl',
  'SERVER_ADDR'             => '192.168.1.100',
  'SERVER_NAME'             => '80',
  'SERVER_PORT'             => '80',
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL'         => 'HTTP/1.1',
  'SERVER_SIGNATURE'        => '',
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE'         => 'Apache',
};

2019/06/25 at 10:07:53 AM
$VAR1 = {
  'DOCUMENT_ROOT'           => '?:/.../urls/6/www/',
  'GATEWAY_INTERFACE'       => 'CGI/1.1',
  'QUERY_STRING'            => 'code=403',
  'REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD' => 'HEAD',
  'REDIRECT_STATUS'         => '403',
  'REDIRECT_URL'            => '/robots.txt',
  'REMOTE_ADDR'             => '185.53.88.37',
  'REMOTE_PORT'             => '58418',
  'REQUEST_METHOD'          => 'GET',
  'REQUEST_URI'             => '/robots.txt',
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME'         => '?:/.../urls/6/cgi/error/.pl',
  'SCRIPT_NAME'             => '/cgi/error/.pl',
  'SERVER_ADDR'             => '192.168.1.100',
  'SERVER_NAME'             => 'localhost',
  'SERVER_PORT'             => '80',
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL'         => 'HTTP/1.0',
  'SERVER_SIGNATURE'        => '',
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE'         => 'Apache',
};

2019/06/25 at 10:48:17 AM
$VAR1 = {
  'DOCUMENT_ROOT'           => '?:/.../urls/6/www/',
  'GATEWAY_INTERFACE'       => 'CGI/1.1',
  'QUERY_STRING'            => 'code=403',
  'REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD' => 'HEAD',
  'REDIRECT_STATUS'         => '403',
  'REDIRECT_URL'            => '/robots.txt',
  'REMOTE_ADDR'             => '77.247.110.106',
  'REMOTE_PORT'             => '54263',
  'REQUEST_METHOD'          => 'GET',
  'REQUEST_URI'             => '/robots.txt',
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME'         => '?:/.../urls/6/cgi/error/.pl',
  'SCRIPT_NAME'             => '/cgi/error/.pl',
  'SERVER_ADDR'             => '192.168.1.100',
  'SERVER_NAME'             => 'localhost',
  'SERVER_PORT'             => '80',
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL'         => 'HTTP/1.0',
  'SERVER_SIGNATURE'        => '',
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE'         => 'Apache',
};

2019/06/25 at 01:46:30 PM
$VAR1 = {
  'DOCUMENT_ROOT'           => '?:/.../urls/6/www/',
  'GATEWAY_INTERFACE'       => 'CGI/1.1',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT'             => '*/*',
  'HTTP_HOST'               => 'default',
  'HTTP_USER_AGENT'         => 'curl/7.64.1',
  'QUERY_STRING'            => 'code=403',
  'REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD' => 'DKEMDIF&0',
  'REDIRECT_STATUS'         => '403',
  'REDIRECT_URL'            => '/.html',
  'REMOTE_ADDR'             => '192.31.231.241',
  'REMOTE_PORT'             => '33716',
  'REQUEST_METHOD'          => 'GET',
  'REQUEST_URI'             => '/.html',
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME'         => '?:/.../urls/6/cgi/error/.pl',
  'SCRIPT_NAME'             => '/cgi/error/.pl',
  'SERVER_ADDR'             => '192.168.1.100',
  'SERVER_NAME'             => 'default',
  'SERVER_PORT'             => '80',
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL'         => 'HTTP/1.1',
  'SERVER_SIGNATURE'        => '',
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE'         => 'Apache',
};

2019/06/25 at 03:14:24 PM
$VAR1 = {
  'DOCUMENT_ROOT'           => '?:/.../urls/6/www/',
  'GATEWAY_INTERFACE'       => 'CGI/1.1',
  'QUERY_STRING'            => 'code=403',
  'REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD' => 'HEAD',
  'REDIRECT_STATUS'         => '403',
  'REDIRECT_URL'            => '/robots.txt',
  'REMOTE_ADDR'             => '77.247.110.106',
  'REMOTE_PORT'             => '61954',
  'REQUEST_METHOD'          => 'GET',
  'REQUEST_URI'             => '/robots.txt',
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME'         => '?:/.../urls/6/cgi/error/.pl',
  'SCRIPT_NAME'             => '/cgi/error/.pl',
  'SERVER_ADDR'             => '192.168.1.100',
  'SERVER_NAME'             => 'localhost',
  'SERVER_PORT'             => '80',
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL'         => 'HTTP/1.0',
  'SERVER_SIGNATURE'        => '',
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE'         => 'Apache',
};
```

Could this instead be a misconfiguration on my router?  Or malware on my machine or router that is phoning home?  If so, how can I check, and can I stop it sooner?

Or is this all just normal chaotic internet traffic that I can ignore and rest easy knowing it won't ever see my private site?

Comment: Without the complete VirtualHost definitions and ordering  it is hard to say, but it seems that site 6 is also the default vritualhost , which means it will respond to all queries that Apache httpd can't match as specifically for  sites 1-5. (based on the `'SERVER_NAME'             => 'default'` entry )

Comment: Didn't know order was a factor so I rearranged them here for flow, last being the one to remember.  In vhosts, localhost is actually the first VH. The second is my public IP which declares `ServerName XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` (obviously with my IP) and no aliases.  Then the other 4 VHs are for the domain names, all declaring `ServerName domain-name-X.com` and `ServerAlias www.domain-name-X.com` with appropriate URLs.  All of the VHs are basically the same with only the DocumentRoot and ScriptAlias (and CGI directory) paths and log file names differing.  I wasn't aware of default.  I'll try adding that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want a virtual host that only responds to queries for `http://localhost` **do not  make that virtual host available on all IP-addresses** with the IP-address wildcard:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  localhost
```

See [the manual for exact VHost matching rules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html) but doing the above gives Apache httpd only a single discriminator to use to select which requests should be handled by this virtual host, namely when the request includes the `Host: localhost` header and it won't verify that the request was made to either the `localhost` IP-address  `127.0.0.1` or the loopback network interface.

Instead bind that VHost to the specific localhost IP-address with either

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName  localhost
```

or the equivalent

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    ServerName  localhost
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of that either.  If I want to have localhost _and_ my local network IP point to the site (for other machines in my local network to have access), would I need to have another VH block or would ServerAlias still suffice?  Or can I use a regular expression like `<VirtualHost (localhost|127\.0\.0\.1|192\.168\.1\.100):80>`?  If multiple are viable, which would you recommend?

Comment: Or apparently this?  <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 192.168.1.100:80> from https://askubuntu.com/questions/543762/how-do-i-stop-default-localhost-virtualhost-from-directing-to-named-virtual-host  That Q/A also mentions that VH and `ServerName localhost` are invalid because localhost is not a fully qualified domain name.

Comment: Picking this as the answer although your comment about order and the default case on the question is what ultimately led me to the solution.  The first VH is implicitly default, so I put the localhost VH last in the config file.  Also things REALLY went haywire when I tried `<VirtualHost localhost:80>`, `<VirtualHost domain-name-A:80>` and such, so I left them all as `<VirtualHost *:80>`.  When trying with specific names instead of *, ALL of the URLs pointed to default (the localhost, as it was still first in the config).